# Oracle/SQL - Using query results as paramaters in another query -looping?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Hi everyone what I'm wondering if I can do is create a table that lists the record counts of other tables.  It would get those table names from a table.  So let's assume I have the table TABLE_LIST that looks like this

```
name
---------
sports_products <-- contains 10 records
house_products  <-- contains 8 records
beauty_products <-- contains 15 records
```

I would like to write a statement that pulls the names from those tables to query them and coount the records and ultimately produce this table

```
name                numRecords
------------------------------
sports_products     10
house_products      8
beauty_products     15
```

So I think I would need to do something like this pseudo code

```
select *
from    foreach tableName in select name from table_list
            select count(*) as numRecords
            from tableName
        loop
```

Comment: Have to use dynamic SQL - SQL doesn't allow a variable to represent a table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a function that is doing this for you via dynamic sql.

However, make sure to declare it as authid current_user. You do not want anyone to gain some sort of privilege elevation by exploiting your function.

```
create or replace function SampleFunction
(
  owner     in VarChar
 ,tableName in VarChar
) return integer authid current_user is
  result Integer;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from "' || owner || '"."' || tableName || '"'
    INTO result;

  return result;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to simply keep your DB statistics updated, use dbms_stats package or EM, and then

```
select num_rows
  from all_tables
 where table_name in (select name from table_list);
```

Comment: This will depend on that sample size for the statistics. If sample size of 100% is used for dbms_stat.gather_table_stats then it will be accurate until any change is made. If a lower sample size is used then even that can't be guaranteed.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this. DBA's can for instance lock the statistics of a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think Robert Giesecke solution will work fine.

A more exotic way of solving this is by using dbms_xmlgen.getxml.

See for example: [Identify a table with maximum rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390945/identify-a-table-with-maximum-rows-in-oracle/391026#391026)

Comment: Yep, that is pretty much the same principle. AFAIK, DBMS_XmlGen is declared as authid current_user, too. So there's also no privilege hassle involved.